# phone authentication using firebaseUI ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm ios fresher. i want to retrieve phone number with country code from the default firebase phone authentication screen.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJPCI.png) is default screen that firebase provides. how can i retrieve country code & phone number on verify buttonClick that is enter by the user and how can i get verify buttonClick event? Is there any library provided function to get buttonClick?

i am stuck here

```
   fileprivate func startLogin() {

            self.authUI?.delegate = self
            self.authStateListenerHandle = self.auth?.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in

                if user != nil {
                    print(user)
                }else {
                    do{
                        try self.auth?.signOut()
                        print("singning out done")
                    }catch{
                        print("Error while signing out!")
                    }

                    let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: self.authUI!)
                    self.authUI?.providers = [phoneProvider]

                    phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self.rootController!, phoneNumber: nil)
                }
            } 
     }
```

this code open phone number login screen for me, bt after providing phone no. when i click to the verify button i have to pass user's phone no. in bellow code to send opt on users mobile, bt i don't know how can i get verify buttonClick event & how can i retrieve phone no. & country code that user input in the phone authentication screen.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(("need to pass phone number with country code here")!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
          if let error = error {
           // self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
            return
          }
          // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
          // ...
        }
```

Please also explain me right flow of verification.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the Firebase methods to access the phone number once the tocken is verified?

Access the tocken and verify the credibility and after that you can use `decodedTocken.phone_number` property . Use below to access the phone number

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
 var uid = decodedToken.phone_number;
 // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

Maybe after you access the phone number you can use the string and break down the country code, just a sugesstion, take a look at the below described answer with how to verify the phone number as well

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227042/10021979